# Vectors and line equations and planes

Tags: vectors

Which of the three coordinate planes does the line given by $x=16t, y=-4-9t, z=34$ intersect?

I am confused where to start with this question. I was thinking maybe to solve $t$ from equation of $y$ but I am unsure.

Comment: For example, to see if it intersects the $y$-$z$ plane, this is when *the other variable is $0$*, i.e. $x=0$. So you need to see if $x=0$ is possible on your line. Similarly for the other two coordinate planes.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you

Comment: **HINT**: If $z=34$, the line is contained in a plane parallel to the $xy$-plane.